# Problems with permissions with squid3

Tags: 14.04, permissions, chmod, squid

I have been trying to get squid to work. I have a configuration for the cache to be created in the directory `/var/cache/squid3/`. However, I get this error when running squid with the "-z" tag (It is the first run):

```
WARNING: Cannot write log file: /var/log/squid3/cache.log
/var/log/squid3/cache.log: Permission denied
 messages will be sent to 'stderr'.
2015/05/23 20:05:39 kid1| Creating missing swap directories
2015/05/23 20:05:39 kid1| /var/cache/squid3 exists
FATAL: Failed to make swap directory /var/cache/squid3/00: (13)
Permission denied
Squid Cache (Version 3.3.8): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.010 seconds = 0.007 user + 0.003 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 22560 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
```

I tried to fix this with typing `sudo chmod 755 /var/cache/squid3`, however also without any success.

The output of `namei -l /var/cache/squid3` is:

```
$ namei -l /var/cache/squid3
f: /var/cache/squid3
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root var
drwxr-xr-x root root cache
drwxr-xr-x root root squid3
```

**UPDATE:**
I made new directories in `/squid3_log` and `/squid3_cache`. I then issued for both:

```
sudo chown -R root:proxy /squid3_log #and squid3_cache
```

and

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /squid3_log #and squid3_cache
```

It fixed the permission denied with squid3_cache but not with squid3_log.

**UPDATE:**
I tried purging, reinstalling, reconfiguring and it worked with first run `squid3 -z`. But then when I ran the debug `squid3 -NCd1`, It showed:

```
2015/06/01 16:24:24| Starting Squid Cache version 3.3.8 for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu...
2015/06/01 16:24:24| Process ID 20379
2015/06/01 16:24:24| Process Roles: master worker
2015/06/01 16:24:24| With 65536 file descriptors available
2015/06/01 16:24:24| Initializing IP Cache...
2015/06/01 16:24:24| DNS Socket created at [::], FD 5
2015/06/01 16:24:24| DNS Socket created at 0.0.0.0, FD 6
2015/06/01 16:24:24| Adding nameserver 127.0.1.1 from /etc/resolv.conf
2015/06/01 16:24:24| Adding domain Home from /etc/resolv.conf
2015/06/01 16:24:24| Logfile: opening log /home/john/squid3_log/access.log
2015/06/01 16:24:24| WARNING: log parameters now start with a module name. Use 'stdio:/home/john/squid3_log/access.log'
2015/06/01 16:24:24| WARNING: no_suid: setuid(0): (1) Operation not permitted
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Unlinkd pipe opened on FD 11
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Local cache digest enabled; rebuild/rewrite every 3600/3600 sec
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Logfile: opening log /home/john/squid3_log/store.log
2015/06/01 16:24:25| WARNING: log parameters now start with a module name. Use 'stdio:/home/john/squid3_log/store.log'
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Swap maxSize 15360000 + 16384 KB, estimated 1182798 objects
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Target number of buckets: 59139
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Using 65536 Store buckets
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Max Mem  size: 16384 KB
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Max Swap size: 15360000 KB
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Rebuilding storage in /home/john/squid3_cache (no log)
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Using Least Load store dir selection
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Current Directory is /home/john
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Loaded Icons.
2015/06/01 16:24:25| HTCP Disabled.
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Sending SNMP messages from [::]:3129
2015/06/01 16:24:25| WARNING: no_suid: setuid(0): (1) Operation not permitted
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Pinger socket opened on FD 17
2015/06/01 16:24:25| /var/run/squid3.pid: (13) Permission denied
2015/06/01 16:24:25| Closing HTTP port [::]:3128
FATAL: Could not write pid file
Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) and the latest version of Squid3

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/627428/edit) your question and add the output of `namei -l /var/cache/squid3`

Comment: @heemayl I have edited it. And as I can see, all is root, and one is squid3? I have no idea what it means

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 11):

`squid3` runs as the user `proxy`, so you set the owner user (and group) as `proxy` and then set permissions accordingly.

You can do the following to change recursively the owner and owner group of all files under `/var/cache/squid3` to user `proxy` and group `proxy` respectively:

```
sudo chown -R proxy:proxy /var/cache/squid3
```

Also make sure the owner has the right permission, the permission you currently have i.e. `0755` will do.

In your case, as you can see the directory `/var/cache/squid3` is only writable by `root`, hence you were getting the permission denied error.

Comment: thanks, but it did not fix. And sorry for the super late reply

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Ubuntu 16.04, Squid 3.5.12), the problem is in standard AppArmor rules and non-standard cache directory, look into `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Sep 26 23:08:34 server2 kernel: [ 6458.643201] audit: type=1400 audit(1506449314.016:36): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mkdir" profile="/usr/sbin/squid" name="/BIG/squid_spool/00/00/" pid=4377 comm="squid" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=13 ouid=13
```

Symlinks doesn't works in this case too.

Possibility solutions:

- Change option `cache_dir` to standard `/var/spool/squid` and not use symlinks in this path;
- Change file `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.squid` and reload apparmor:

  ```
  sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.squid
  ```

  But you may have small problems on updates.
- Mount separate partition for Squid cache.

Answer (score 0):

change owner to proxy for your installed directory
sudo chown proxy:proxy /usr/local/squid -R
and set proxy user in squid.conf

vi /usr/local/squid/etc/squid.conf
cache_effective_user proxy

Then restart the squid, your permission denied issue gone and WARNING: Cannot write log file also resolved.

I have tested in  ubuntu 14.x of my system and then comment here